# Windows batch file outputs "| was unexpected"

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

I am trying to get a list of relative paths excluding the .git directory and it's contents. But get this error

> ```
> | was unexpected at this time.
> ```

When trying to run this batch file.

```
@echo off
SET "StartPath=%cd%"

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /B /ON /S  "!StartPath!" |find /i /v ".git" ') DO (
    set "SubDirsAndFiles=%%f"
    set "SubDirsAndFiles=!SubDirsAndFiles:%StartPath%=!"
    IF EXIST "!StartPath!\!SubDirsAndFiles!\" (
        REM Echo This is a folder...
        ECHO !SubDirsAndFiles!\
    ) ELSE (
        REM Echo This is a file...
        ECHO !SubDirsAndFiles!
    )
)
```

How can I successfully implement this part that is causing the error:

> ```
> |find /i /v ".git"
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the "|" with a caret.
See the code below.
I have also added an extra echo so you can spot another problem with your code.

```
@echo off
SET "StartPath=%cd%"

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /B /ON /S  "!StartPath!" ^|find /i /v ".git" ') DO (
    set "SubDirsAndFiles=%%f"
    set "SubDirsAndFiles=!SubDirsAndFiles:%StartPath%=!"
    echo "CHECK:[!StartPath!\!SubDirsAndFiles!\]"
    IF EXIST "!StartPath!\!SubDirsAndFiles!\" (
        REM Echo This is a folder...
        ECHO !SubDirsAndFiles!\
    ) ELSE (
        REM Echo This is a file...
        ECHO !SubDirsAndFiles!
    )
)
```